# Trying to create and update wordpress from python library

Tags: api, wp-api, python

**The Background**:
I am a software developer that is trying to create a sports analytics website. I used to created wordpress-based sites on the side so I have a WHM where I can host sites.  I'd prefer to host the site here because it is already paid for :-).
Anyway, on my team's game days I want to create a post / content that I will update regularly with the fancy stats, graphics, etc.  I plan on purchasing a theme that I will use as the template for my site.  I have a working knowledge of wordpress and posts.

**The Question**:
What is the best way to go about this?  I've spent the last little bit googling this and I can see that there is an API available and lots of examples of creating simple posts.  That said, do I really want to try to create and send a whole lot of html in my code?  The layout for these pages would be roughly the same (there will be a section for each period of the game, and I will fill in the content for that area when the data is made available).

The only thing I really, really want to avoid is a php-heavy solution.  The data science part of this is hard enough - I don't want to become a php expert.

**Possible solutions:**

- Creating a hidden post with tags that I can look for to do a search and replace.  Maybe I would create a new post from that post?  I haven't investigated this year to see if it is possible in the api.
- A custom post type with custom fields.  I haven't done much in this area.  If I did, I would need utilize one of the post types that came with whatever theme I am purchasing.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving the wordpress api a go, and so far things are good.  I found it easier to build an example post in the UI, retrieve the post using the API, and then use the retrieved fields to build a new post.